# RegEx to replace trailing underscore with number of a string

Tags: regex

I have an ID that looks like this: `prefix_my-awesome-slug_123`

Now I would like to have a regular expression that removes the underscore and number on the end (`_%d`).

Comment: Using which regular expression engine?

Comment: Also... do you want to *replace* (as per the title) or *remove* (as per the body of your question)?

Comment: Ok, i needed it in PHP so here is the workin result:

$my_id = 'prefix_my-awesome-slug_123';
$my_new_id = preg_replace('/_[0-9]+$/', '', $my_id);

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/_[0-9]+$/` - easy. Just replace the match with an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

for perl like regex implementations this should do it:

```
s/_\d+$//
```